# Как получить код приложения, написанного на Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Приложение написано на Objective-C (для iOS). Можно ли как-то узнать, какие интерфейсы присутствуют в приложении и как оно выглядит на уровне кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно узнать какие есть Objective-C интерфейсы и методы с помощью `otool`:

```
otool -tv <исполняемый файл> | grep "\]\:"
```

Comment: Отлично! Это то, что нужно.